# Color Highlighter package not working on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using the package/plugin Color Highlighter in Sublime Text 3 (build 3211) on Windows 10 but it doesn't work the highlighting. I already turned on the option "Inline Highlighting Style" as **filled** in Tools > Color Highlighter > "highlight colors in selected text" | "highlight colors when hovering the cursor above them" | "highlight colors in all text".

Nothing happens:

[image]

The "color picker" tool, available when clicking with the right button of the mouse, was working. I tried to uninstall and install the package again and now is not aswell (nothing happens when clicked).

[image]

Do you have any other option to install it and make it work?

Comment: I recently had similar issues getting Color Highlighter to work, so I uninstalled it and installed [`ColorHelper`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorHelper), and it's been working great.